# Количество разных элементов в масиве

Tags: java, массивы, count

Задание: найти количество разных элементов в массиве. Первый способ работает корректно, второй не работает. Подскажите, в чем причина? Второй способ выглядит проще и более распространенный вариант подсчета.

```
int []arr = {3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 97};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length-1; j++) {
        if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
}

//первый способ

int uniqueNumber = arr.length; // создаём переменную с начальным значение, равным размеру массива (предолагаем, что все уникальны значения)
for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){ // пробегаемся по массиву
if(arr[i-1]==arr[i]) uniqueNumber--; // если смежные элементы равны, то значение uniqueNumber уменьшаем на единицу
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println(uniqueNumber);

//второй способ

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]!=arr[i+1])
        count++;
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Integer[] arr = {3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 97}; Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(arr)); System.out.println(mySet.size());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас первый элемент не учитывается, счет должен быть с единице или при нахождении первых двух различных элементов нужно счетчик увеличивать на 2. Плюс цикл должен быть до `arr.length-1` элемента иначе получите ошибку `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` так как элемента и индексом `arr.length` в массиве быть не может.

```
 int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            if(arr[i]!=arr[i+1]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

А можно еще сделать с помощью коллекции Set например вот так:

```
Set<Integer> uniqueElements = new HashSet<>(Arrays.stream(arr)
                                                    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));

        System.out.println(uniqueElements.size());
```

Comment: я всё-таки за TreeSet

Comment: @Vartlok, а почему же? Ведь добавление в HashSet быстрее.

Comment: работать быстрее будет

Comment: @Vartlok, в HashSet вроде добавление за константное время происходит в то время как в TreeSet за log(n).

Comment: В теории, а в реальности там лист(на счет АррейЛист был не прав) в каждой корзине и всё превращается в N/количество_корзин

Comment: @Vartlok тогда можно самому написать свою реализацию хеш таблици, там кода строчек 10-15.  Можете использовать бор, сложность N*log(MAX)...

Comment: @pavel и всё равно это будет N против log(N) =)

Comment: @Vartlok почему `log(N)`?) для хеш таблицы `O(N)` для дерева `O(N * log N)`.

Comment: Для хеш таблиц константа (O(C) а не O(N), это есть в документации к HashSet - "This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)..." (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = {3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 97};

List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!tmp.contains(arr[i])) {
        tmp.add(arr[i]);
    }
}

System.out.println(tmp.size()); // 6 {3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 97}
```

Comment: Тогда уж лучше Set и TreeSet использовать

Comment: Спасибо за вариант решения.